# Trouble with menu and slider visibility

Tags: jquery, css, menu, slider

Hover products or example to see the problem.
Maybe someone has encountered this problem in the past and knows exactly what's wrong.
I did my best through the css code both menu and slider replacing the positioning from absolute into relative and so on.Almost got my answer when I changed the picture positioning from absolute to inherit but wasn't enough, it's does the trick partially. 
In a nutshell, I'm stuck so any other ideas would be appreciated.

```
.lof-slidecontent { position:relative; overflow:hidden; border:#F4F4F4 solid 1px;}
.lof-slidecontent .preload{ height:100%; width:100%; position:absolute; top:0;   left:0;    z-index:100000; text-align:center; background:#FFF}
.lof-slidecontent .preload div{ height:100%;    width:100%; background:transparent url(../images/load-indicator.gif) no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;}

.lof-slidecontent  .sliders-wrapper{    position:relative;  height:100%;    width:900px;    z-index:3px;    overflow:hidden; }
.lof-slidecontent  ul.sliders-wrap-inner{overflow:hidden;   background:transparent url(../images/load-indicator.gif) no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;  padding:0px;    margin:0;   position:relative;  overflow:hidden;}
.lof-slidecontent  ul.sliders-wrap-inner li{overflow:hidden;    padding:0px;margin:0px; float:left; position:inherit;}
.lof-slidecontent  .lof-opacity  li{position:absolute;  top:0;  left:0;     float:inherit; }


.lof-slidecontent  .navigator-content {position:absolute; bottom:10px; right:10px;
background:url(../images/transparent_bg.png) repeat;
padding:5px 0px;
   }
.lof-slidecontent  .navigator-wrapper{  position:relative;  z-index:10;
height:180px;
width:310px;
overflow:hidden;
color:#FFF;
float:left
    }
```

somewhere around here would be the problem maybe the z-index ?

here's the complete code and the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/melbourne/vjG56/

Comment: There are javascript errors in your jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:` and `z-index` to the menu like this:

```
.menu, .menu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```